# Axiom of union definition

Tags: set-theory

I have seen in a certain script the following definition for a union of sets:

∀A ∃C [(x ∈ C) ⇔ (∃A'(A' ∈ A) ∧ (x ∈ A'
))]

And I am fine with this and understand it. Now further it is said that the following (simpler) definition of a union is derived from the one above, namely:

∀A, B ∃C ∀x[x ∈ C ⇔ ((x ∈ A) ∧ (x ∈ B)]

I have two questions about this. First, I would like if someone could show how this second one is derived from the first. Second, I am confused about the '∧'(AND) operator in the second definition, shouldn't it be the OR operator?

Comment: Yes, it should be an OR in the second. But please typeset your mathematics using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observation that $\wedge$ should be changed into $\vee$ here is correct.

The second formula is linked with a union of **two** sets $A,B$ with $A\cup B$ or (denoted alternatively) $\bigcup\{A,B\}$ as result.

Using the first formula we get:$$\forall\{A,B\}\exists C[x\in C\iff\exists A'\in\{A,B\}\;[x\in A'\vee x\in A']]$$This can be modified to:$$\forall A\forall B\exists C[x\in C\iff(x\in A\vee x\in B)]$$

The second definition is actually weaker that the first because it is focused on pairs $A,B$.

Comment: (And the statement in the last paragraph can be made formal: In ZF minus the axiom of union, the second version of union is provable, but not the first.)

Comment: How can you go from 

$\exists C[(x\in C)\Leftrightarrow(\exists A'(A'\in\{A,B\})\land(x\in A'))]$ 

to 

$\exists C[(x\in C)\Leftrightarrow(\exists A'\in\{A,B\}[x\in A'\vee x\in A'])]$ ?

Is there some formal rule that allows this transformation?

Comment: @Eduard Formally $\exists u\in v[\phi]$ (where $\phi$ is some formula) is not more than an abbreviation of $\exists u[u\in v\wedge\phi]$.